# android architecture components with instant app

Tags: android, module, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps, android-architecture-components

I want to make my app ready for instant apps.
I have created an app module, base module and a feature module.
if I run my project in this configuration everything works great.

when i implement the following lines inside my base module Gradle file.

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
```

the Gradle build succeeds but I lose my default activity and can't run the project. the default activity is inside my base module manifest.

if i change the extensions line with implementation.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
```

the following error happens:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.3) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

does anyone knows what the problem can be?

Comment: Are you using v26.1.0 or later of support libraries?  If so, that now includes `Lifecycles` (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-1-0) ....as such you might be running in to mismatch between it's transitive dependency and version you're including,

Comment: Silly question, but what's meant by losing your DefaultActivity? api is a better choice for a library in the base module that will be used by the feature modules.

Also you can try running `gradle -q :<base module name>:dependencies --configuration implementation` to see where the duplicate libraries are happening

Comment: I had this same issue and I ended up removing the lifecycle dependency.

Comment: The problem was by having two dependencies on the library. I used the 26.1.0 support lib and included the lifecycle also what created the error.

@John O'Reilly For the "DefaultActivity" I mean your activity with the main intent filter. by using the api and not implementation i have included probably more libs than needed and the run configuration could not longer found the main intent filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the support lib 26.1.0 or higher the lifecycle functionality is included inside. by removing the following lib lines

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
```

and only using the :

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

everything was working again.

[Official document reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-1-0)

Comment: Another lifesaver. I'm very happy you got marked as the rightful answer for this.